# The Theoretical Minimum: Lecture 5, Exercise 3. Finding equations of motion from potential energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential-energy

From Leonard Susskind's book *The Theoretical Minimum*.

> "A particle in two dimensions, x and y, has mass m equal in both directions. It moves in a potential energy $V = \frac{k}{2(x^2+y^2)}$. Work out its equations of motion. Are there circular orbits? If so, do they all have the same period? Is the energy of the system conserved?"

I managed to work through the previous exercise, where the potential was $V = \frac{k(x^2+y^2)}{2}$. But this time I'm struggling to come up with a differential equation I can solve. I'm studying A-level maths and further maths, so please keep any answers well-explained! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this problem is using the effective potential formalism. If you are in a central potential (one that only depends on $r$, where $r^2 = x^2+y^2$, which you have) then there are some tricks you can use to simplify your problem. Writing down the Lagrangian for a 2D particle in polar coordinates:

$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2 + r^2\dot{\theta}^2) - V(r)$

One of the Lagrange equations will give us a conserved quantity since our Lagrangian does not depend on $\theta$:

$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = 0$
$\implies \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = mr^2\dot{\theta} \equiv l$ (which is constant over time.)

The other Lagrange equation will give us an equation of motion for the radius:

$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial r}$
$\implies m \ddot{r} = -\frac{d}{dr}(\frac{l^2}{2mr^2} + V) \equiv -U'(r)$

where $U(r)$ is called the effective potential. Notice if $U'(r)=0$, then $r$ will be constant (if there is no radial velocity), i.e. you have circular orbits. Thus you can solve the $U'(r)=0$ equation to get the radius of the orbits. Then, from the initial angular velocity (which you provide yourself as an initial condition) you can get the period of the orbit.

For the question of energy conservation, it is known that since your potential does not depend on time, then the energy (E = $\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2 + r^2\dot{\theta}^2) + V(r)$) is conserved. If you want to check, you can take the time derivative of $E$ and you will see how this goes to $0$.

Comment: Why is it not $-\frac{d}{dr}(-\frac{l^2}{2mr^2}+\frac{k}{2r^2})$?

Answer (score 3):

The general orbit is not going to have an analytic solution. Just focus in the circular orbits and ask what their period is.

Good luck with your A-Levels!